# How to know which tab is selected and active in in the set of dynamic generated tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to know the language tab selected while uploading file from the set of dynamic generated tabs. It should also pass the language selected.

Here I have selected French language tab form the 3rd set. I have chosen 3rd set from which the file will be uploaded. Now I need to recognize the selected language to pass the value via my ajax call.
[image]

Below is the function to add new tabs:

```
function buildTabsNew() {
    var questions = jsonResponse;
    var newTabs = [];
    var langlength = questions[0].DetailLanguages.length;
    console.log(questions[0].DetailLanguages);
    for (var k = 0; k < langlength; k++) {
        counter++;
        languageSelected = questions[0].DetailLanguages[k].Language_Name;
        var tabsArray = {
            paneId: "paneid-" + counter,
            title: questions[0].DetailLanguages[k].Language_Name,
            content: '<textarea class="textarea-' + hash + k + '" placeholder="' + questions[0].DetailLanguages[k].Language_Name + '" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px;"></textarea><div id="uploadFile-' + hash + k + '"></div>',
            active: k == 0 ? true : false,
            disabled: false
        };
        newTabs.push(tabsArray);
        console.log(newTabs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the concept that the tab with "active" class is the one we need so the code will be:

`console.log($("ul.nav-tabs li.active a").text());`

PS: This might create an issue if you have more than one nav-tabs present in the same page. I think if you start using id attribute that would be better.

Comment: If I want to know the selected language of the tab from which upload button is clicked then what is the solution.

Comment: The answer does not change much but we would require an indepth understanding of the relevant HTML Structure.